# embedded SSH in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, ssh

I am working on an webserver that provides a webpage to enter information details about a remote server ( ip, username, password), a txt file ( a scriptin python), some arguments and then push a button to execute the script on the remote server.
For this, I created a client in HTML and a server in node.js. The client sends the data and the node.js is able to receive it . However, I need my server to be able to take the username and password and execute the script through ssh.
I could not find how to invoke SSH in javascript in order to execute something like: ssh root:password@1.2.3.4 "python ./test.py" ( as an exemple)
It is my first time working with javascript in depth and node.js

Comment: [Shameless plug for my simple-ssh module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh) Visit the GitHub page for information on how to use it.

Comment: If you're sending plaintext passwords like that, I hope you're *at least* using HTTPS between the client and the web server.

Comment: @mscdex I am indeed using HTTPS between client and webserver. Otherwise, what would yo suggest to use?